# Linkedin V2 API (POSTMAN)

Tags: postman, linkedin-api

I want to create application Which will share post in company page.

I have  Permissions in linkedin :
[image]

Using documentation im trying to get Token. but i have error :

```
{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "This application is not allowed to create application tokens"
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin/context

[image]

*** Real credentials was Replaced by  xxxxx

Answer (score 1):

Use this [Postman Collection](https://www.postman.com/collections/457103a8893956b90f80) for the LinkedIn Oauth 2.0 API. And follow these steps in [this article](https://esther-liao.medium.com/how-to-get-a-linkedin-access-token-a53f9b62f0ce)

Answer (score 0):

All the permissions you have are 3-legged permission and you are trying to get token using 2-legged process. 
Please follow below workflow to create access/bearer token using 3-legged flow: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context

> If your application needs access to information from a member's LinkedIn profile, use the Authorization Code Flow to request permission from the member.

PS: Company page post also requires Authorization Code Flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Postman Collections](https://www.postman.com/linkedin-developer-apis?tab=collections) here to view some examples and use cases.

An update documentation for Postman Oauth 3 is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/postman-getting-started)

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps in this [article](https://esther-liao.medium.com/how-to-get-a-linkedin-access-token-a53f9b62f0ce)

```
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?
client_id=yyyyy
&redirect_uri=xxxx
&scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_member_social
&response_type=zzzzz
```